# Log4j2 creates unwanted logfile

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I want to set the log level and the filename and the filepath of the logfile. I found a way to do this and it all works but log4j create an additionla logfile.
I got the following log4j2.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="OFF">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="logFile" filename="${sys:logDir}${sys:logFilename}" >
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c{1}:%L - %msg%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="logFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

In my main function I set ${sys:logDir} and ${sys:logFilename}:

```
    import config.ReadParameterFile;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig;

import java.io.IOException;

public class main {
private final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(main.class);



    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        ReadParameterFile config = new ReadParameterFile();

        LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        Configuration config1 = ctx.getConfiguration();
        LoggerConfig loggerConfig = config1.getLoggerConfig(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);


        switch (config.getProtokollProtokollTiefe()){
            case "Default":loggerConfig.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
                break;
            case "Produktion":loggerConfig.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
                break;
            case "Test":loggerConfig.setLevel(Level.FATAL);
                break;
            default:System.out.print("falsche Logtief");


        }


        System.setProperty("logDir",config.getProtokollDirProtokoll());
        System.setProperty("logFilename", config.getProtokollDateinameProtokoll());
        ctx.reconfigure();
        ctx.updateLoggers();



    }

}
```

It's working like I want but log4j create a file called "${sys:logDir}${sys:logFilename}" in my main project path. Why is log4j2 doing this? I guess it initialize the logfile before I can set the name. How can I change it?

Kindly Regards!

I could solve the prob with the following main:

```
public class main {


    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        ReadParameterFile config = new ReadParameterFile();

        System.setProperty("logDir",config.getProtokollDirProtokoll());
        System.setProperty("logFilename", config.getProtokollDateinameProtokoll());
        switch (config.getProtokollProtokollTiefe()){
            case "Default":System.setProperty("logLvl","DEBUG");
                break;
            case "Produktion":System.setProperty("logLvl","ERROR");
                break;
            case "Test": System.setProperty("logLvl","ALL");
                break;
            default:System.out.print("falsche Logtief");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Try to remove `private final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(main.class);`?

Comment: You are using `RollingFile` which means new files will be created at specific point of time defined by file pattern  or if file exceed size defined by `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy`. 
See more about configuration: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

Comment: @Aris2World Hey, yes I tried this already. there is still the wrong file.

Comment: @Rafal Hey, I changed my log4j2.xml file. But still got the wrong file. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Every ref to LogManager initialize the logger. You have to change approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do:

```
private static ReadParameterFile config;
private static Logger log;
static {
    config = new ReadParameterFile();
    System.setProperty("logDir",config.getProtokollDirProtokoll());
    System.setProperty("logFilename", config.getProtokollDateinameProtokoll());
    log = LogManager.getLogger(main.class);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The logger is declared as a static field. This is initialized when the class is loaded, *before* the `main` method is called.

The first call to `LogManager` should come after these system properties are set. 
You can either initialize the Logger after setting the properties, or set the properties on the command line with the `-D` option.